# Naming rows in a large dataset by vector with different letters and numbers

Tags: r

I am trying to rename rows in my dataset. I need to change them like this: first row would be named "IL1", second "IL2",..., "ILn", where n is a number of rows in the dataset.
I know how to change it by for example rownames(df) <- c("IL1","IL2","IL3","IL4"). But type it word by word is possible only in smaller datasets. I need to change it in dataset where are hundreds of rows.
Any ideas? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can  use `paste0`:

```
rownames(df) <- paste0("IL", 1:nrow(df))
```

Comment: Thank you so much Chris!

Comment: Thanks for this. Did you know you can also accept an answer by clicking the tick mark in the left upper corner?